# Is there a way to make a CircularProgressIndicator or Future last a minimum amount of time (when making a HTTP request)?

Tags: flutter, dart

For context, suppose I have Flutter code which displays a `CircularProgressIndicator` while code is being fetched from an API:

```dart
Future<void> getItems() async {
  setState(ViewState.Busy);
  items = await _api.getItems();
  setState(ViewState.Idle);
}
```

So that the `CircularProgressIndicator` does not display for only a fraction of a second (which I find disrupts the flow of related animations), I want to make this indicator display for a minimum amount of time.

I *think* I can solve this problem using the Future API or a timer, by somehow setting the *minimum* amount of time a HTTP request future can take. How can I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this pattern frequently.  Future-wait accept a list of Futures.  It executes them all in parallel and returns will all have completed.  I think it looks much cleaner.

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-async/Future/wait.html

```
  List<Future> futures = [];
  futures.add(Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)));
  futures.add(_api.getItems());
  await Future.wait(futures);
```

Comment: It executing in parallel in very clean, concise code indeed makes it a great answer! I'll accept this answer but thanks to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest idea would be to add booleans which check if both the timer and response have executed

```dart
Future<void> getItems() async {

  setState(ViewState.Busy);

  bool gotResponse = false;
  bool timerExpired = false;

  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
    timerExpired = true;
    if (gotResponse) setState(ViewState.Idle);
  });

  items = await _api.getItems().then((items) {
    gotResponse = true;
    if (timerExpired) setState(ViewState.Idle);
  });

}
```

The basic idea is to call `setState(ViewState.Idle)` only if both Async operations have completed and corresponding bools are `true`

Comment: This is indeed a better solution than I had.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in your getTimes function:

```dart
Future<void> getItems() async {
  setState(ViewState.Busy);
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: amountOfSeconds));
  items = await _api.getItems();
  setState(ViewState.Idle);
}
```

Here it will wait x amount of seconds.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there any way to introduce a lower bound without adding a sequential delay?

Comment: I don't understand what you just said. I am not a native English speaker so could you give a explenation about what you meant?

Comment: I think a best approach is to call your API, and them, if it's response time is less than X seconds, you use ` await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: amountOfSeconds));` before your setState.
The implementation provided by @BlueDragon709 can turn your app too slow if the API doesn't return immediately, because you will wait twice.

Comment: As @siega mentioned it wasn't the best solution. I would indeed recommend to use the answer that Ajil O. provided above.

Answer (score 1):

I created and use the following extension method for this purpose:

```
extension FutureExtensions<T> on Future<T> {
  Future<T> withMinDuration({
    Duration duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
  }) async {
    final delayFuture = Future<void>.delayed(duration);
    await Future.wait([this, delayFuture]);
    return this;
  }
}
```